# How to implement a search which could give whole site results in o365 SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

We want to implement a search which can give results for searched keyword from whole site in o365 SharePoint.

Kindly suggest what are the best ways to achieve it, any reference material would be supper helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can click "Organization" after searching from search box, and then you will get the result from the whole O365 SharePoint.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Quick question, is it possible to customize the search page template according to requirement?

Comment: AFAIK, I'm afraid it is impossible to customize the search result page in SharePoint Online.